# Photoshop: final blend for semi-transparent pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

I have an image, which have some amount of semi-transparent pixels. I would like to blend them with white:

**Source**

[image]

**Wanted**

[image]

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to technically blend them with white; you want to change the opacity to 100% , which is what your second image looks like. Put the art (lavender and black) on a separate layer from your background (if yo want to maintain a transparent backround) and change the transparency slider to 100%

Comment: That's a tricky one: layer itself is 100% not transparent, but it contains pixels with different opacity (RGB**A**).

Comment: @Denis Kulagin: Check your paint brush is set to full opacity, and the flow also, and brush mode set to normal.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a few ways to solve this, but no matter which approach you take, you’re going to have to re-work or trace the edge.

#### Option 1: Paint underneath

One simple, but slow way to do this, is to paint underneath with white. You can do this with a shape layer, or a bitmap layer. If the stroke is opaque and wide enough, this will likely be the easiest way to go.

#### Option 2: Duplicate the layer

Another option is to open the image, and make lots of copies of the layer.

1. Duplicate the layer the image is on, using `⌘J`.
2. Do this a few times… `⌘J`, `⌘J`, `⌘J`, `⌘J`, `⌘J`.
3. Select all the layers and merge them.
4. Duplicate the newly merged layer a few times.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until all the transparency is gone.

This will give you the the result you’re after with one major flaw: The partially transparent edges will now be aliased (jagged). You’ll have to use a different technique for fixing the edges.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to give you a straight answer on that.
But through the images you've posted you already answered it.

I would:
  1 create a new layer bellow the art one
  2 create a lasso selection along the black line of colored area
  3 fill with white.
Then I would CTRL+E or Cmd+E both layers.